# Crash report log

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app

I'm an Android app beta user. I keep encountering crash on my Android phone. I rarely use the stackexchange app for more than 5 minutes without crashing.
In the Help page there is a sentence "Crash reports are automatically reported back to us." How can I get the log of crash report? I'm wondering whether all the forced close events I encountered are treated as "crash" and reported back or not.

Comment: If it force-closes and you're wondering whether it's being reported, just click the "report" button on the window that comes up.

Comment: @Emracool but no window came up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every single time the app crashes or becomes non-responsive, we automatically get told. There's no way for you to look at it yourself in the app and we're most likely not going to make one. If you use an app off the Play Store (for example, aLogcat) or the `logcat` utility if you have a developer environment, you'll be able to see it in your device's log.